# Bootstrap .center-block not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

**[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3368/)**. I want to make the  center align using bootstrap. All I want 2 things

1) Make the `ul` center align

2) As `ul`'s `width` **should NOT** be like `20%` or something like that. I want it to be `width: auto;` because number of `li`s is dynamic.

I tried following code

```
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">

        <div class="center-block">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a class="link-text-bright-blue" href="#2015-14" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><h5>2015 &amp; 2014</h5></a></li>
                <li class=""><a class="link-text-bright-blue" href="#2013" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><h5>2013</h5></a></li>
                <li class=""><a class="link-text-bright-blue" href="#2012" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><h5>2012</h5></a></li>
                <li class=""><a class="link-text-bright-blue" href="#2011" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><h5>2011</h5></a></li>
                <li class=""><a class="link-text-bright-blue" href="#2006-2010" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><h5>2006 - 2010</h5></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
          ... Other div
        </div>

     </div>
```

Comment: share your jsfiddle code.

Comment: @user4429928 JSFIddle attached.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905019/center-unordered-list-navbar-bootstrap-3

Comment: @pevoje I donot want to add any extra css (specially media queries). All I want a pure Bootstrap technique.

Comment: what do you mean by making the ul center align?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[is it not what justified nav does?](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified)

Also remember that when using `.center-block` you need to add `float:none;` as it is missing in bootstrap

Make the ul center align

```
.center-block {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3384/

**Note:** you were missing a div in your jsfiddle for the row class

Comment: How `.nav-justified` help to centered align the `ul`?

Comment: check its code in source, it'll help you. Also updated my answer

Comment: In the documentation it is listed that >Justified navbar nav links are currently not supported. If I am wrong then can you come-up with JSFIdle example?

Comment: you are not wrong, the source says it. However, If I got your question correctly, you would simply need to remove borders not to let it look like tabs.

Comment: Nope .. I want `ul` to be `.center-block`ed.

Comment: don't understand what you mean with center-block. center to what?

Answer (score 2):

The `.center-block` only works within a `div` or tag with a *defined width*.

Otherwise, you'll have to add `float: none;` to the css `.center-block{}`.

It is posibble also with `align` or `text-align` `=center;`, but know that center-block was created for not to do this.

**Note that the [bootstrap css](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center) already includes within the class `.center-block` the following:**

```
// Class
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

// Usage as a mixin
.element {
  .center-block();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3371/

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.navbar {
    border: 1px solid transparent;

    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar-right {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: inline-block !important;
    float: none !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-header {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left !important;
}
```